# Seperation linear functional question

Tags: linear-algebra

This question prepares for a theorem I am reading, but I am not entirely sure the proof of the statement.

For distinct points $x,y \in X$, must there exist a linear functional $\phi(x) \neq \phi(y)$? The answer should be yes, but how to show the existence? It seems like contradiction is the technique but that is not illuminating to the conjecture. I mean if the distinct points have admission of $\phi$, this means $x - y \not\in Ker(\phi)$, but I cannot deduce further from this.

Comment: You can just construct a linear functional s.t. $x-y\not\in Ker(\phi)$. For instance, define $\phi$ by $\phi(x-y) = 1$, $\phi(v) = 0$ for all $v\in\operatorname{span}(x-y)^\bot$.  Then extend by linearity to the rest of the space.

Comment: A good principle to keep in mind about linear maps (including linear functionals) is that they are defined by their action on a basis.

Comment: @Bye_World ah this is a linear functional not just a map. I can guess one can use such reduction